# jQuery - same behaviour for click and keypress events

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, keyboard

I'm programming a simple memory game, and need to make it usable both with mouse and keyboard. I'm able to build the listeners for the arrow keys in order to move in the cards grid, but I can't let the Enter key event emulate the "click" event, that launchs the openCard function.
Here's the code:

-HTML (this is basically the cards grid)

```
<div id="game_container">
        <div id="game_board">
            <div id="card1" class="browsable colorcard firstinline"><div class="colour"></div></div>
            <div id="card2" class="browsable colorcard"><div class="colour"></div></div>
            <div id="card3" class="browsable colorcard"><div class="colour"></div></div>
            <div id="card4" class="browsable colorcard lastinline"><div class="colour"></div></div>
            <div id="card5" class="browsable colorcard firstinline"><div class="colour"></div></div>
            <div id="card6" class="browsable colorcard"><div class="colour"></div></div>
            <div id="card7" class="browsable colorcard"><div class="colour"></div></div>
            <div id="card8" class="browsable colorcard lastinline"><div class="colour"></div></div>
            <div id="card9" class="browsable colorcard firstinline"><div class="colour"></div></div>
            <div id="card10" class="browsable colorcard"><div class="colour"></div></div>
            <div id="card11" class="browsable colorcard"><div class="colour"></div></div>
            <div id="card12" class="browsable colorcard lastinline"><div class="colour"></div></div>
            <div id="card13" class="browsable colorcard firstinline"><div class="colour"></div></div>
            <div id="card14" class="browsable colorcard"><div class="colour"></div></div>
            <div id="card15" class="browsable colorcard"><div class="colour"></div></div>
            <div id="card16" class="browsable colorcard lastinline"><div class="colour"></div></div>                
            <div class="fixfloat"></div>
            <div id="msg"></div>
        </div>
```

and here is the jQuery part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".colour").hide();
$("#game_board div").click(openCard);
$(".browsable:first").addClass("selected");

shuffle();

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var cur_idx = $(".browsable").index($(".selected"));
    var max_idx = $(".browsable").length - 1;
    var row_length = 4;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 13:
            // Perform some action when enter is placed
            // HERE should I define what happens when I press ENTER
            break;
        case 37:
            // Navigate left
            if (cur_idx === 0) {
                var next_idx = 0;
            } else {
                var next_idx = cur_idx - 1;
            }
            break;
        case 38:
            // Navigate up
            if ((cur_idx - row_length) <= 0) {
                var next_idx = 0;
            } else {
                var next_idx = (cur_idx - row_length);
            }
            break;
        case 39:
            // Navigate right
            if (cur_idx === max_idx) {
                var next_idx = cur_idx;
            } else {
                var next_idx = cur_idx + 1;
            }
            break;
        case 40:
            // Navigate down
            if ((cur_idx + row_length) >= max_idx) {
                var next_idx = max_idx;
            } else {
                var next_idx = (cur_idx + row_length);
            }
            break;
    }
    if (typeof next_idx !== 'undefined') {
        $(".browsable.selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(".browsable").eq(next_idx).addClass("selected");
    }
});

function openCard() {

    id = $(this).attr("id");

    if ($("#" + id + " .colour").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#game_board div").unbind("click", openCard);

        $("#" + id + " .colour").slideToggle('fast');

        if (coloropened === "") {
            boxopened = id;
            coloropened = $("#" + id + " .colour").css("background-color");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#game_board div").bind("click", openCard);
            }, 300);
        } else {
            currentopened = $("#" + id + " .colour").css("background-color");
            if (coloropened !== currentopened) {
                // close again

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#" + id + " .colour").fadeOut(1000);
                    $("#" + boxopened + " .colour").fadeOut(1000);
                    boxopened = "";
                    coloropened = "";
                }, 400);
                points--;
                $("#points").html("" + points);
            } else {
                // found
                $("#" + boxopened + ".colorcard").css('visibility', 'hidden');
                $("#" + id + ".colorcard").css('visibility', 'hidden');
                found++;
                points++;
                boxopened = "";
                coloropened = "";
                $("#points").html("" + points);
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#game_board div").bind("click", openCard);
            }, 400);
        }

        count++;
        $("#count").html("" + count);

        if (found === 8) {
            $("#msg").show();
        }
    }
}

$('#restart_button').click(function() {
    resetGame();
});
```

});

Thanks!

Comment: is $(e.target).click() not working for you?

Comment: General tip for key handling with jQuery: use `e.which` instead of `e.keyCode`, because different browsers do different things with these properties but jQuery normalises `e.which` for you.

Comment: I solved it. The first parameter of the bind() function must be "keydown" and not "click" to make it work. Thanks to you all :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Trigger to call click event.... also insted of Keycode try which....
this will work for capturing **Enter** key event:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $("#game_board div").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: The keydown event will be triggered by the Enter key, but keypress likely won't be triggered for the arrow keys.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that I can't make the function openCard by pressing Enter, that is why I'm stocked :)